How to format label ticks of QValueAxis
In Python, we can set data formatting to "align right with a given offset". It will look like this print('{:4d}'.format(42)) or like this print('{:>4}'.format('42')). How to make such formatted data labels on one of the graph axes?
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCharts import QLineSeries, QChart, QChartView, QValueAxis
import sys
import math
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)


class Chart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        self.data = [math.sin(i * 0.1) for i in range(0, 1000, 1)]
        self.series = QLineSeries()
        for i in range (0, 1000, 1):
            self.series.append(i, self.data[i])
        self.axisX = QValueAxis()
        self.axisY = QValueAxis()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        self.axisX.setLabelFormat("%d")
        self.axisY.setLabelFormat("%d")                          # ?!
        self.chart.setAxisX(self.axisX)
        self.chart.setAxisY(self.axisY)
        self.chart.axisY().setRange(-2, 2)
        self.chart.axisX().setRange(0, 1000)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.axisX)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.axisY)
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        self.chart_view = QChartView(self.chart)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.chart_view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Chart()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Failed to use methods setLabelFormat & LabelFormat.
